# hiding converted picklist values in lead status Field

Tags: lead-conversion, web2lead

I have a lead process "Sales Manager". Now, i have list of picklist values "New","Process","Waiting","Finished". While configuring the picklist values, their are default values atleast one value need to select.  With out selecting the default values it is showing error like "At least one converted status must be selected" .

If i select one of the converted status("Qualified") then it is saving. When i open the lead, status field is showing this converted status value.

Is their any option to hide the picklist value("Qualified")? .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that if you edit your picklist, and click on `Qualified`, you'll discover that the box for `converted` is checked for it. You can uncheck that option if you want. You could create two `recordTypes`, one for leads that are `open` and haven't been converted and another for `closed leads`. That might be the easiest option. In that way, when you do convert a lead, you could automatically set it to `Closed-Converted` when the recordtype is changed (or `Closed - Not Converted` if applicable). In that way, a lead is only set to converted when it's actually converted, not when someone manually checks a box.